# Single selection for every UITableViewSection iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios, multipleselection

I have a UITableView with 2-3 sections. I want to implement a functionality where single row from every section can be selected.

Something like so :-

[image]

I have tried enabling multiple selection on the UITableView. But it allows me to select multiple rows from all the sections. I want to select only one row at a time from every section.

```
 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);


                if (cell.Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.None)
                {
                    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                }


            selectedSection = indexPath.Section;

        }
        public override void RowDeselected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list to store flags for every section which you selected last time.

```
 List<NSIndexPath> selectList = new List<NSIndexPath>();
 for(int i = 0; i < tableviewDatasource.Count; i++)
 {
      //initial index 0 for every section
      selectList.Add(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, i));
 }

public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //anti-highlight last cell
    NSIndexPath lastindex = selectList[indexPath.Section];
    var lastcell = tableView.CellAt(lastindex);
    lastcell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;

    //highlight selected cell
    var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;

    //update the selected index
    selectList.RemoveAt(indexPath.Section);
    selectList.Insert(indexPath.Section, indexPath);
}
```

[image]